# WinForm: textbox is not updated in event handler for FormClosing

Tags: c#, winforms, formclosing

My question is very simple: why the property `tbInfo.Text` (a `TextBox` object) does not get updated? 
It remains set to "DEFAULT"!

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{       

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.tbInfo.Text = "DEFAULT";

        this.FormClosing += (o, e) =>
        {
            int timeInterval_ms = 1000;

            for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
            {
                int sec = (3 - i);
                this.tbInfo.Text = $"Application will be closed in {sec} seconds";
                Thread.Sleep(timeInterval_ms);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Using the debugger I see that the event handler is correctly called when I close my application clicking on the "X" button (aka the event `FormClosing` is fired).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `this.tbInfo.Update();`just before the sleep command

Comment: @GuidoG Neat! this works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

You're pausing the UI thread with your `Thread.Sleep`, so nothing will be updated, you wait three seconds and the window closes.

Use a timer instead. You also would have to prevent closing the form in your `FormClosing` event handler so that the timer will actually run and then close the window after three seconds have elapsed from the timer's event handler.

Something like the following perhaps:

```
var closeForReal = false;

FormClosing += (sender, e) => {
  if (!closeForReal) {

    var timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000 };

    timer.Start();

    var count = 3;
    timer.Tick += delegate {
      if (count == 0) {
        closeForReal = true;
        Close();
      }
      tbInfo.Text = $"Application will be closed in {count} seconds";
      count--;
    };
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Good point with "pause"! You are right! I added a timer.Start() and Interval = 1000 because it did not compile!

Comment: @eddie: Yeah, it was meant more as a starting point. I've thrown this together without being able to test it. And since there are lots of timers in .NET with different APIs I always tend to forget how to use each of them properly ;)